# Camel Bindy: providing the class to use in spring.xml

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, bindy

I am sure I have missed something really obvious but just haven’t worked it out.

We use bindy to extract a CSV file into a POJO . This has been working nice and well. We have been given some more CSV files to load. This is where I discovered the issue. Bindy doesn’t allow multiple classes to have the `@CsvRecord` annotation to live in the same package if you do a package scan. But that is ok since we use camel 2.13.3 and I can see that the constructor for `BindyCsvDataFormat` allows us to pass in a class.

The trouble I am having is, we use `spring.xml` to setup `camel`. I can’t seem to get the `BindyCsvDataFormat` to use the class constructor. It will only use the one that does a package scan.

```
<bean id="bindyDataformat" class="org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.csv.BindyCsvDataFormat">
    <constructor-arg value="com.something.package.Model.class" />
</bean>
```

The above didn’t work. I suspect it is with me passing a string as the `constructor-arg` so the string constructor is always called. 
Is there a way to get `BindyCsvDataFormat` to not do the package scan and to allow me to provide the class I want the csv data unmarshalled to in the `spring.xml`?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971651/pass-hardcoded-constructor-arg-classt-to-bean-via-spring-config

Comment: Yes, it did help. It was in fact the answer I was looking for. Many Thanks.  If you make an answer i will mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not specific to bindy. It's a common problem where you need to inject the "value" of a `Class` via Spring DI.

Here's a link that describes how to do pass a class argument properly:

[pass "HardCoded" Constructor Arg Class<T> to bean via Spring Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971651/pass-hardcoded-constructor-arg-classt-to-bean-via-spring-config)